# I have this really old game from the DOS era, anyone know how to run it in my modern machine?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, dosbox, abandonware, test-drive-3-the-passion

I have a copy of Test Drive III: The Passion, but whenever I run it in my Windows XP machine it runs too fast. Is there any way to run this game in a modern computer?

Comment: Just press the turbo button, of course. What? Your new computer doesn't have a turbo button? Probably Steve Jobs' fault.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a DOS emulator called [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) that supports this game.  [Get full details on DOSBox support of Test Drive 3 here](http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=270&letter=T), along with some helpful comments.

You can download all the Test Drive games for free at [abandonia.com](http://www.abandonia.com/games/385/TestDrive-TriplePack).

Comment: DOSBox is the way to go!

Answer (score 4):

There is a program called [Mo'Slo](http://www.hpaa.com/moslo/) that will slow down games for you so that the become playable on modern hardware.

Comment: i remember using that on an old Win ME back in around 2000, to play Wing Commander II or something like that... :-)

Comment: Anyone know of a good freeware alternative to Mo'Slo?

Answer (score 2):

You already have [dosbox] tagged. Have you already tried Ctrl+F11? [This tutorial](http://www.classicdosgames.com/tutorials/dosbox.html) has some more tips.

You also have [abandonware] tagged. You should probably know that the legal standing for that is about as firm as piracy of modern games. Which is to say, it's the same. Just old.

Comment: As far as I know, abandoneware does not mean it's old. It means there is no one to enforce it (it has no owner, as the old owner no longer exists and no one gained the rights to it) An old game which is still owned by a company, is not abandoneware.