# How to limit an older game's (DirectX 3) FPS speed? (USNF 97)

Tags: technical-issues, backwards-compatibility, graphics-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have this really old game from the DOS era, anyone know how to run it in my modern machine?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/620/i-have-this-really-old-game-from-the-dos-era-anyone-know-how-to-run-it-in-my-mo)

I'm trying to run USNF 97 Navy Fighters (was made for Windows 95). My computer runs XP and everything runs and installs flawlessly. Just the actual game itself runs about 2-3 times too fast.

I've tried a ton of slowdown programs before, but none really seem to work (they run with lagspikes and turn the sound into a mess). Also turning on V-Sync didn't work for me. Compatibility mode for Win95 also did not work. The actual problem is there is no FPS limit for the DirectX renderer. The game was designed for a pentium 100.

I've read about FPS limiters for newer games (e.g. FSX) but they only support DX8-9 :(
If only I could recompile it and add a crappy fps limiter myself, but thats out of my league.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: rendering speed =/= game speed, in the 99% of the games

Comment: try running the game 2 times in the background :P

Comment: Can you list the fps limiter or "slowdown" programs that you've used?

Comment: duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/620, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8420, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38268

Comment: @e-MEE: It's somewhere uncommon now (not as low as 1% though), but back in 1995, it was extremely common for games to be [fixed timestep](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step).  And many of them did not have fps-limits, because rendering *too* fast was simply not an issue at the time.  So, running some of these games on modern machines will result in hundreds of frames *(of both rendering and logic)* per second.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try a program called DOSBox.  It is designed for running older games that often do exactly what you've described.

http://www.dosbox.com/

(Just noticed the age of this question...  Well maybe this will still help someone.)

Comment: Is there any reason to launch a Win95 DirectX-enabled game via DOSBox?